# Where can I find old versions of Acrobat Reader (<9.4) in deb form?

Tags: repository, versions, adobe-acrobat

It turns out that apparently Adobe has disabled movie playback in newer versions (9.4 and up) of Acrobat Reader in Linux.

Where can I find deb packages of older versions?

The idea is to overwrite the currently installed version (9.5.1) in Ubuntu 12.04.
There are some launchpad repositories, with, for example, acroread-9.3.3-1lucid1.deb but the file shows as "(deleted)".

Comment: As far as I know, the latest version of the Acrobat Reader (for Unix) with movie support is 9.4.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the older versions of Acrobat Reader here:

- ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/

It has versions 7.x, 8.x and 9.x.

Comment: Although the older version I tried still cannot play the movie, this what I was looking for.

Comment: I never even knew Acrobat Reader could play movies.  Sorry it didn't help.

Comment: I am not sure now, I got that impression from here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/how-to-include-a-movie-in-a-pdf-step-by-step-instructions/60678#comment129463_60678. Thanks.

Comment: I started to read it, but I got a headache and now I need to lie down. :)

Comment: yeah, it is hard to follow if you are not familiar with TeX, the first part of the answer reads ". Sadly, there is no media playback (except for 3D) in AR for linux since v. 9.4.1. It was disabled for obscure reasons."

Comment: I noticed that.  That was about the only part I could follow without my eyes glazing over. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check it here - https://www.my-acrobat-reader.com/

You can find all previous versions for Linux and UNIX from 1 to 11.

Good luck!